# please help me to understand these circuit tester light-up patterns

Tags: electrical

I am using an inexpensive VAC/DC Sperry 80-500 circuit tester and a detector that tells me which circuit breaker in the panel controls the outlet. House (northeastern USA) was built in the 1940s.

An old wire with two conductors comes up from the basement and terminates at a two-prong outlet in the foyer; a wire with two conductors comes down from a light switch on the wall that controls the light in the foyer ceiling. That wire is also attached to the two-prong outlet.

I plug the line-tracer into the outlet, its red indicator light lights up, and then I go down to the basement. The device makes a rapid buzz at breaker #34 in the box. I flip the breaker OFF and come back upstairs to find that the red indicator light of the tracer plugged into the outlet is now OFF, as expected.

But the foyer ceiling lamp is still ON.

I detach the four wires from the outlet and the ceiling light goes OFF.

We now have these four bare wires down at the baseboard in the foyer:

```
      from ceiling light switch
       xxxx 
       xxxx 
       xxxx
       |  | 
       C  D



A  B
|  |
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
from basement
```

With the circuit breaker in the basement still flipped to OFF, and now using the circuit tester:

A + B  =  no light on the tester
C + D  =  no light on the tester

A + C   = faint light on the tester
A + D   = bright light on the tester

B + C   = faint light on the tester
B + D   = faint light on the tester

Does this mean that there is electricity flowing through the wire that comes from the ceiling light switch?

Comment: Is there another switch that controls this foyer ceiling light?

Comment: Yes, there is one on the second floor at the top of the stairs.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all switch boxes involved? I have a theory about what's going on here, but will need the photos to confirm it

Comment: The photos wouldn't show the wiring clearly. Is there something the photos should focus on?

Comment: Perhaps you should make a wiring diagram of the setup then?

Comment: I don't really know what wires are going where and wouldn't trust to get it right.  If AB is dead because circuit 34 is OFF down at the circuit panel, would the lights on the tester suggest that wire CD is drawing power from a different circuit, and that two circuits are meeting at the outlet?

Comment: That's close to what I'm suspecting -- is there another breaker in the panel that turns the foyer ceiling light off?

Comment: I will try to figure out which breaker controls the foyer ceiling light.

Comment: Couldn't figure out which breaker controls the foyer ceiling light. My indicator didn't beep even with multiple level adjustments and repeated attempts to locate it. Phoned an electrician.

Comment: Yeah -- it sounds like you need a pro at this point.  Tell them that you suspect a *Carter system 3-way* is in play (I sure do!) and they should be on the lookout for that